# Не получается вывести данные из ajax запроса

Tags: ajax, reactjs

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

```
function Tab(props) { return (
<div>
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>Main</p>
    <p>Temp</p>
    <p>Pressure</p>
    <p>Wind</p>
</div>
); } class Field extends React.Component { constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { weather: { main: {}, name: null, weather: {} } }; }; $.ajax({ url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=e577a0ae7c86e26f8068b341b02315da", success: function (data) { const state = this.state; state.weather = { main: data.main, name: data.name, weather: data.weather[0], wind: data.wind}; } }); render() { const a = 1; return (
<div>
    <form action="" encType="text/plain">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter location</legend>
            <label>
                <input type="text" id="city" value={this.state.value}/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="country" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <Tab/>
    <Tab/>


</div>
); } }; ReactDOM.render(
<Field/>, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Проблема в переменной weather которая не доступна(undefiend).
В то же время не получается функцию Tab для отдельных окон объявить внутри Field.
Пожалуйста подскажите как сделать так чтоб можно было выводить полученные по API данные во множество вкладок с погодой для введённых городов.

Comment: 1) Нужно объявить дефолтный state для weather

Answer (score 0):

1) Нужно объявить дефолтный state для weather
2) создать функцию с xhr или axios для получения данных и выставлять state в componentDidMount . https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html 
3) Отрендерить массив полученных значений в цикле

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел на ваш код. У вас запрос просто лежит в компоненте получается? Тогда рекомендую поместить ваш запрос внутрь [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). А также советую менять стейт через метод [`this.setState(...)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) - это правильный подход к смене состояния компонента.

> [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) - вызывается сразу после монтирования компонента.
>   Обычно используется для загрузки данных через запросы или место для
>   настройки подписки на события. Если нужно что-то сделать с
>   DOM-элементами, то лучше здесь, вызывается после отрисовки, а значит
>   после `render`. Вызов `setState` в этом методе вызовет дополнительный
>   рендеринг, но это произойдет до того, как браузер обновит экран. Это
>   гарантирует, что даже если `render()` будет вызываться дважды в этом
>   случае, пользователь не увидит промежуточное состояние.

Поэтому код вашего компонента будет таким:

```
class Field extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        weather: {
          main: {},
          name: null,
          weather: {}
        }
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=e577a0ae7c86e26f8068b341b02315da",
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({
            weather: {
              main: data.main,
              name: data.name,
              weather: data.weather[0],
              wind: data.wind
            }
          });
        }
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }); 
    }

    render() {
        // const a = 1; // это не понятно зачем вообще
        return (
        <div>
           <form action="" encType="text/plain">
               <fieldset>
                  <legend>Enter location</legend>
                  <label>
                     <input type="text" id="city" value={this.state.value}/>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                     <input type="text" name="country" />
                  </label>
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
               </fieldset>
           </form>
       </div>);
    }
};
```

Также советую обратить внимание на `$.ajax` запрос, я добавил обработку ошибки:

```
error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

В случае ошибки в консоли отобразится детальная информация по ошибке, вдруг запрос упадет с ошибкой или еще что-то. Также мне не нравится функция `function Tab(props) {...}` - если вы ее дергаете внутри рендера таким образом:

```
<Tab/>
<Tab/>
```

то это вкорне не верный подход потому что это вылядит как отрисовка компонента, а не вызов функции (уберите этот код из рендеринга на время), вообще избегайте вызова функций внутри метода рендеринга - это приводит к дополнительному ререндерингу, что добавляет глюков и тормозов на страницы.

Также, для `this.state.value` я задал начальное значение в конструкторе, чтобы там не упала ошибка на отсутствующее свойство в стейте компонента. Функцию 
 `function Tab(props) {...}` я тоже советую пока убрать.